# How to get Machine IP Address using beanshell in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to write a script in beanshell for jmeter through which I can get the IP address of a machine (using `ipconfig` command and extract only IP Address from the output)?

The following code is giving only the IP of the request of which needs to be passed to jmeter.

```
String IP = InetAddress.getByName(prev.getURL().getHost()).getHostAddress();
vars.put("IP", IP);
```

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use as follows:

```
log.info("IP " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
String IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
vars.put("localIP", IP);
```

later, you can refer the IP using the following syntax:

```
${localIP} or vars.get("localIP")
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitri and Naveen...these both are working....how can I  copy ip address in a variable... From the logs

Comment: store the value using vars.put

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
vars.put("IP", org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIP());
```

Demo:

[image: Beanshell IP]

You can also use [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function in the "Parameters" section and refer the value as `Parameters` or `bsh.args[0]` in the script body

References:

- [JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIp()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#getLocalHostIP())
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your code you can use a single line variable `${__machineIP}` which is given by JMeter. Make sure we utilize inbuilt feature given by JMeter and if it does not satisfy then only you should go for other options. 
So you can use `${__machineIP}` or `${__machineIP()}`.
In some of the cases it needs to be inside `double quotes("")`, Make sure where you need to use `""` and where is not.